# Change characters with ÅÄÖ to AAO unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have approx 300 images, lots of them got Å, Ä or Ö in it and I want to be effective but I am not so good with the terminal. I googled but didn't find a line that worked.

Images can be like:
`Ängelholms.jpg` or `BBC Örebro.jpg`, or `Bräckt.jpg`.

I did try something like:

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" `echo $file | tr ' ' '_'` ; done
```

I used this one to replace spaces to underscores and it didn't seem to work with the letters I want to change.

How should I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to research if `tr` is an appropriate tool, you can test with `echo "Ä" | tr 'Ä' 'x'`, etc. You may need to prefix something like `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8` (or what ever your local language is). Good luck.

Comment: In addition to all the self-built answers here: [detox](https://linux.die.net/man/1/detox) is a program for things like that.

Answer (score 3):

`tr` does not handle translation of multi-byte characters well. `sed`, on the other hand, has no problem with UTF-8 characters. You could do something like the following:

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed 'y/ÅÄÖåäö/AAOaao/'); done
```

This of course presumes your entire set of characters that need translation are described by `/ÅÄÖåäö/AAOaao/`. You would need to increase the number of characters in your translation set to encompass all potential characters in `$file`.

An example of the correct handling of the translation with `sed` is:

```
$ echo "ÅÄÖåäö.png" | sed 'y/ÅÄÖåäö/AAOaao/'
AAOaao.png
```

There may be more efficient ways of doing this, but with POSIX shell, this was the first that came to mind.

Comment: You have me at a disadvantage. I'm not sure I get NFD? I don't know if it will or won't??

Comment: [Unicode normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization).

Comment: Ahh, thank you. But, damn, I still can't answer you question. I'm not sure how, or if, the shell would even handle such characters. If it's not in some extended character set the shell understands, I don't see how it could.

Comment: I can: it won't work. But you can always normalise to NFC with the uconv utility: `echo ... | uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -x any-nfc | sed ...`

Comment: You have now taught me, and I have learned, two new things tonight -- it's been a good night. Thanks. (p.s. I didn't even have `icu` (International Components for Unicode) installed -- I do now...)

Comment: I don't think the shell performs any Unicode normalization of its own, though a properly Unicode-aware implementation of a text-processing utility like `sed` (or even, heavens `tr`, ideally) would know about normalizations, and deal correctly with them.

Comment: Also, you cannot *portably* assume that `sed` works properly with UTF-8 in this scenario. You could use `perl -CSD` and maybe read up on whether the earliest versions which had these options actually implemented them correctly right off the bat.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know, GNU tr(1) does not support non-ASCII characters yet.
(Or am I outdated?)

With Perl, I would say:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use Encode;

for $filename (<*>) {
    ($new = decode('UTF-8', $filename)) =~ tr/ÅÄÖåäö/AAOaao/;
    rename $filename, $new;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you don't want to do the looping in Perl for whatever reason, the core of the beef here (pardon the mixed metaphors) is `perl -CSD -pe 'y/ÅÄÖåaö/AAOaao/'`

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
while read -r char replacement; do
    for file in *"$char"*; do
        mv "$file" "${file//$char/$replacement}"
    done
done <<'____'
    Å A
    Ä A
    Ö o
    å a
    ä a
    ö o
____
```

Using the Bash built-in string replacement functionality should easily make this a lot faster than spawning multiple processes for each file name, though you'll notice that it's possible that we rename a file multiple times to achieve the desired result with this code. (I suppose it would not be too hard to refactor it to avoid this if it's important.)

You'll notice that `${var//string/replacement}` is a Bash extension which is not available with regular `/bin/sh` (so the dependency on Bash needs to be marked explicitly in the shebang line if you put this in a script).

Comment: I'm slightly dubious of the necessity of doing this in the first place. If you are serving these images over HTTP the links to file names need to use an explicit, unambiguous file name encoding, but modern HTTP servers have no trouble with that -- though the file names will be unsightly, like `%C3%96rebro.jpg` if your encoding is UTF-8.